# How to iterate through index of set of set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

I have `mySet` initialized with Set. Now, this set adds another new Set. After this, I want to iterate through set of set:

```
{Set(0){...}, Set(0){...}, Set(0){...}, ...}
How to iterate             ^ particular index?
```

Here's the code to demonstrate my issue:

```
const mySet = new Set()
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  mySet.add(new Set())
}
for (let it of mySet[3rd index]) { // how to???
}
```

Similarly, I also need to add into particular set:

```
mySet[3rd index].add('my value')
```

Set has become hard for me in this scenario. Can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a specific index from `Set` by turning it into an array by using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and get the index you want.

For example.

```js
const mySet = new Set()

mySet.add(new Set([1, 2, 3]));

const firstItem = [...mySet][0]
// const firstItem = Array.from(mySet)[0]

firstItem.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: Ouch, this was easy than I thought. Thanks.

Comment: javascript sets are unordered so you shouldn't think in terms of "first" element or "nth" element by index.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the nested set by destructuring with an index.

```js
const mySet = new Set()
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    mySet.add(new Set([i]))
}

const { 3: set3 } = [...mySet];
console.log(...set3);
```